# Database with 5 Tables with Insert and Select

Tags: sql, android, sqlite, select, insert

my problem is that i have 5 tables and need inserts and selects.

what i did is for every table a class and there i wrote the SQL Statements like this

```
    public class Contact

private static String IDCont = "id_contact";
    private static String NameCont = "name_contact";
    private static String StreetCont = "street_contact";
    private static String Street2Cont = "street2_contact";
    private static String Street3Cont = "street3_contact";
    private static String ZipCont = "zip_contact";
    private static String CityCont = "city_contact";
    private static String CountryCont = "country_contact";
    private static String Iso2Cont = "iso2_contact";
    private static String PhoneCont = "phone_contact";
    private static String Phone2Cont = "phone2_contact";
    private static String FaxCont = "fax_contact";
    private static String MailCont = "mail_contact";
    private static String Mail2Cont = "mail2_contact";
    private static String InternetCont = "internet_contact";
    private static String DrivemapCont = "drivemap_contact";
    private static String PictureCont = "picture_contact";
    private static String LatitudeCont = "latitude_contact";
    private static String LongitudeCont = "longitude_contact";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";
        public static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        IDCont + "INTEGER not NULL," +
        NameCont + " TEXT not NULL," +
        StreetCont + " TEXT," +
        Street2Cont + " TEXT," +
        Street3Cont + " TEXT," +
        ZipCont + " TEXT," +
        CityCont + " TEXT," +
        CountryCont + " TEXT," +
        Iso2Cont + " TEXT," +
        PhoneCont + " TEXT," +
        Phone2Cont + " TEXT," +
        FaxCont + " TEXT," +                
        MailCont + " TEXT," +
        Mail2Cont + " TEXT," +
        InternetCont + " TEXT," +       //website of the contact
        DrivemapCont + " TEXT," +       //a link to a drivemap to the contact
        PictureCont + " TEXT," +            //a photo of the contact building (contact is not a person)
        LatitudeCont + " TEXT," +
        LongitudeCont + " TEXT," +
        "primary key(id_contact)" +
        "foreign key(iso2)";

and my insert looks like this

    public boolean SQL_INSERT_CONTACT(int IDContIns, String NameContIns, String StreetContIns,
                    String Street2ContIns, String Street3ContIns, String ZipContIns, 
                    String CityContIns, String CountryContIns, String Iso2ContIns,
                    String PhoneContIns, String Phone2ContIns, String FaxContIns,
                    String MailContIns, String Mail2ContIns, String InternetContIns,
                    String DrivemapContIns, String PictureContIns, String LatitudeContIns,
                    String LongitudeContIns) {
        try{
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "contact" +
                "(" + IDCont + ", " + NameCont + ", " + StreetCont + ", " + 
                Street2Cont + ", " + Street3Cont + ", " + ZipCont + ", " + 
                CityCont + ", " + CountryCont + ", " + Iso2Cont + ", " + 
                PhoneCont + ", " + Phone2Cont + ", " + FaxCont + ", " + 
                MailCont + ", " + Mail2Cont + ", " + InternetCont + ", " + 
                DrivemapCont + ", " + PictureCont + ", " + LatitudeCont + ", " + 
                LongitudeCont + ") " +
                "VALUES (" + IDContIns + ", " + NameContIns +", " + StreetContIns + ", " +
                Street2ContIns + ", " + Street3ContIns + ", " + ZipContIns + ", " +
                CityContIns + ", " + CountryContIns + ", " + Iso2ContIns + ", " + 
                PhoneContIns + ", " + Phone2ContIns + ", " + FaxContIns + ", " + 
                MailContIns + ", " + Mail2ContIns + ", " + InternetContIns + ", " + 
                DrivemapContIns + ", " + PictureContIns + ", " + LatitudeContIns + ", " + 
                LongitudeContIns +")");
        return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;   
        }

    }
```

i have a DBAdapter class there i created the database

```
 public class DBAdapter {

         public static final String DB_NAME = "mol.db";
            private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
            private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";      //to log

            private final Context context;
            private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context context) 
            {
                this.context = context;
                OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
                this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

     public static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
        {

            public OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(Contact.SQL_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(Country.SQL_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(Picture.SQL_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(Product.SQL_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(Project.SQL_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "
                    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL(Contact.SQL_DROP);
            db.execSQL(Country.SQL_DROP);
            db.execSQL(Picture.SQL_DROP);
            db.execSQL(Product.SQL_DROP);
            db.execSQL(Project.SQL_DROP);
            onCreate(db);
        }
```

i found so many different things and tried them but i didn't get anything to work...
i need to know how can i access the database in my activity
and how i can get the insert to work
and is there sth wrong in my code?
thanks for your help

thats how i tried to get it into my activity

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {


private Context context;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maintabactivity);

    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();



    Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this,MapOfLight.class);
    //Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this,Test.class);              //Testactivity
    //Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this,DetailView.class);        //DetailView
    Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this,ObjectList.class);      //ObjectList
    //Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this,Gallery.class);           //Gallery
    Intent intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this,ContactDetail.class);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_mol").setIndicator(this.getText(R.string.mol), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_mol)).setContent(intent1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_highlights").setIndicator(this.getText(R.string.highlights),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_highlights)).setContent(intent2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_contacts").setIndicator(this.getText(R.string.contact),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_contact)).setContent(intent3));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);



    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBAdapter dh = null;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);


    dh = new DBAdapter(this);
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    dh.SQL_INSERT_COUNTRY("AT", "Austria", "AUT");

}
```

}

i tried it with my country table because it has only 3 columns

```
public class Country {

    private static String Iso2Count = "iso2_country";
    private static String NameCount = "name_country";
    private static String FlagCount = "flag_image_url_country";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "country";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    Iso2Count + " TEXT not NULL," +
    NameCount + " TEXT not NULL," +
    FlagCount + " TEXT not NULL," +
    "primary key(iso2_country)";

    public boolean SQL_INSERT_COUNTRY(String Iso2CountIns, String NameCountIns, String FlagCountIns) {
        try{
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "country" +
                "(" + Iso2Count + ", " + NameCount + ", " + FlagCount + ") " +
                "VALUES ( " + Iso2CountIns + ", " + NameCountIns +", " + FlagCountIns + " )");
        return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;   
        }

    }
```

another question is it better to put the insert and select from each table into a separate class, so i have 1 class for each table or put them all into the DBAdapter class?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Anything at all?

Comment: Please specify your exact problem(s). Can't connect to DB? INSERT fails? ... Don't forget to show the relevant error message(s).

Comment: i don't get any error messages it just force closes.

Comment: I suggest you extract the SQL statements you are trying to execute and run the query directly on the database using the appropriate tool for your server (you don't say which you are using: SQL Server, Oracle etc.) Once you know the statements work you can then move them back in to your code.

Comment: i'm programming android and i'm using SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm not sure you have shown all your code and therefore I'm not sure my answer is helpful. Where do you declare the variables IDCont, NameCont, StreetCont ... ? I assume they are constants defining the names of your fields. In which case my answer is not correct as that should form a valid `INSERT` statement.

Can you add the error messages you are seeing as well as being more specific on the DB server you are using?

---

<strike>Your `INSERT` statement will not work because you are inserting the values of the variables passed to the function, instead of specifying the names of the columns.</strike>

The first part of the statment should be all one string:

```
"INSERT INTO contact (IDCont, NameCont, StreetCont, Street2Cont, Street3Cont, ZipCont," + 
    "CityCont, CountryCont, Iso2Cont, PhoneCont, Phone2Cont, FaxCont, MailCont, " +
    "Mail2Cont, InternetCont, DrivemapCont, PictureCont, LatitudeCont, LongitudeCont) " 
"VALUES ("IDContIns + ", " + NameContIns +", " + StreetContIns + ", " +
            Street2ContIns + ", " + Street3ContIns + ", " + ZipContIns + ", " +
            CityContIns + ", " + CountryContIns + ", " + Iso2ContIns + ", " + 
            PhoneContIns + ", " + Phone2ContIns + ", " + FaxContIns + ", " + 
            MailContIns + ", " + Mail2ContIns + ", " + InternetContIns + ", " + 
            DrivemapContIns + ", " + PictureContIns + ", " + LatitudeContIns + ", " + 
            LongitudeContIns +")"
```

I would also question your table design, why are most of the fields `TEXT` and not a more appropriate data type?

Comment: yes i forgot to add them sry these are the exact column names. i need to know how exactly i can access the database in my activity and how i call the insert. i added the way i tried the last time.

Comment: what do u mean with "a more appropriate type"? they're all texts.

Comment: Yes they contain text but do they all need to be able to store a large amount of text? The MySQL docs say "For BLOB and TEXT data, the information is stored internally in a different area of memory than the row buffer" which could lead to performance issues "Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory ... Use of disk incurs a performance penalty, so include BLOB or TEXT columns in the query result only if they are really needed."

Comment: u mean like nvarchar(10)?  i remember, that i read about android/SQLite that u don't have to specify how long the text is, cause it gives the needed space automatically(dynamic).

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a server based SQL engine as you had not specified them in your question or tags. In which case I'm no expert on SQLite or Android so someone else might be able to help.

Comment: can you help me, how i can access the database and get the insert to work in my maintabactivity?